# How to run common code before all onclick handlers in a React app? (to work around Safari middle-button click bug)

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, dom-events, stoppropagation

How can I run code before all `onclick` handlers in a React app without having to add code to each handler? Specifically, I want to globally make sure that middle-button clicks are ignored by all React `onclick` handlers. The goal is to work around a [12-year-old WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22382) where Safari emits a `click` event when the middle mouse button is pressed, instead of the [`auxclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) event that's [mandated](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#ref-for-click%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A3) by the W3C standard and that's emitted by Chrome and Firefox.

Because some users accidentally trigger middle button clicks while scrolling with the mousewheel, I'd like to ignore these accidental clicks globally.  How?

The code I want to inject is very simple:

```js
if (e.button !== 0) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

But I'm not sure where to inject it so that it will run before all event handlers in my app.

One potential complication is that I don't want to ignore middle clicks completely (because browsers have a default behavior that middle clicking on an `<a>` element will open the link in a new tab). Instead, I just want to prevent react from doing anything with those invalid `click` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this I thought I'd have to do something tricky like monkey-patching React, but it turned out that a non-tricky solution was possible: just wrap the entire app in a top-level component that captures click events using the [`onClickCapture`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events) event instead of the normal `click` event. Here's a simple component I wrote for this purpose.

### IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks.tsx

```js
import React, { useCallback, MouseEventHandler, ReactNode } from 'react';
export default function IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const onClick = useCallback<MouseEventHandler>(e => {
    if (e.button !== 0) {
      // Prevent middle clicks from being handled by click handlers on Safari
      // browsers, in order to work around this 12-year-old WebKit bug:
      // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22382
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }, []);
  return <div onClickCapture={onClick}>{children}</div>;
}
```

If you're not using TypeScript, here's a plain JS version of the component:

### IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks.js

```js
import React from 'react';
export default function IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks({ children }) {
  const onClick = useCallback(e => {
    if (e.button !== 0) {
      // Prevent middle clicks from being handled by click handlers on Safari
      // browsers, in order to work around this 12-year-old WebKit bug:
      // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22382
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }, []);
  return <div onClickCapture={onClick}>{children}</div>;
}
```

### Usage

```js
import React from 'react';
import IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks from './IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => console.log('Left clicked!')}>
          click me!
        </button>
      </div>
    </IgnoreSafariMiddleClicks>
  );
}
```

One gotcha I discovered was that [`SyntheticEvent.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) doesn't work in this scenario, because other React event handlers continue to be called afterwards. I had to use the `stopPropagation` method of [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

It took a while for me to figure out this solution (especially the capture-phase trick and the `stopPropagation` vs. `stopImmediatePropagation` issue), and I didn't see this middle-button-swallowing solution anywhere else online, so posting it here to help the next person searching for a solution.

An alternative solution could be to add a polyfill that replaced Safari's bad `click` events with standards-compliant `auxclick` events, but Google [didn't return anything promising](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22auxclick%22%20%22polyfill%22) and writing an event polyfill is beyond my limited knowledge of React's event handling, so I opted for the wrapper-component solution above.